# iPad - Server side documents using WebDav

Tags: objective-c, ipad, webdav

We have an iPad application that allows to access a documents repository using WebDav. 
We would like to let the user view but also modify those WebDav files the easiest as possible, but to do so we have 2 problems:

1) Find the installed programs associated with the server side document type
We use UIDocumentInteractionController that works perfectly with local files, but fails if we pass it a WebDav document URL. Is there a way to get it work with a remote document?

2) Find a program that allows to open/save server side documents through WebDav (rather than local copies).
If we use for example Pages, we can successfully make it open a WebDav document, but looks it indeed makes a local copy. Then when we try to modify and change it, Page saves its own local copy unless the user asks to share the document to a (complex) WebDav URL with credentials. Does someone knows an application that would allow to open directly the remote WebDav file as Microsoft Word looks to do, or at least allows to save the file directly on the server.
If it doesn't exist, how could we automate the sync/transfer of the changed file from our application? If the application saves the document to its own storage, how our iPad application could access it to send it back silently to the server?

Thanks for any hints

Nicolas

Comment: I will ask the question more clearly: How can my application let the user edit a word document within an another app and get the modified doc back?? Is there a way without implementing/using an editor component directly in my app? IOW is really Apple sandbox so restrictive???!